# Which directories to provide for pg_upgrade?

Tags: docker, postgresql

I have docker container with [postgres](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) 12 and I want to upgrade it to 13.
This image stores data and configs in `/var/lib/postgresql/data` dir:

1. `show data_directory;` returns that directory
2. `postgresql.conf` is stored in that directory

I tried to execute pg_upgrade with that directory (in old pg12 volume) as old data and config directory argument: `docker run --name migrate13 -v pg12_volume postgres:13 su postgres -c "cd /tmp && pg_upgrade -b /var/lib/postgresql/data -d /var/lib/postgresql/data -B /var/lib/postgresql/data13 -D /var/lib/postgresql/data13"`

Error `check for "/var/lib/postgresql/data/postgres" failed: No such file or directory` is returned. I failed to find what this error means: I provided wrong data or config directory?

What right directories should contain and how to find them?

Comment: usually you create a new containment or use a already created one?

Comment: I never migrated this db before. So usually I do nothing. Now I want to create new pg13 container with old volume with existing shemes and data